# Sign Requests using RSA-SHA1 with ServiceStack's HttpUtil methods

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

Is there a support to sign requests using RSA-SHA1 when using Servicestack's httputil methods?

Thanks
rudrvij

Comment: I expect you could implement it yourself with request or response filters.

Answer (score 1):

No, [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) is a just a thin lightweight abstraction over .NET's HttpWebRequest.

ServiceStack does maintain some useful [RSA and AES utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/encrypted-messaging#source-code) to support its [Encrypted Messaging](http://docs.servicestack.net/encrypted-messaging) and [JWT AuthProvider](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) features, but these aren't used in its [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils) or [C# Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client).